# how to take user input and convert to uppercase in assembly

Tags: assembly, user-input, nasm, x86-16, uppercase

im trying to take a user input, lowercase and convert into UPPERCASE in assembly.
I compiled this in NASM but it gives an error.

```
IDEAL

MODEL small;
STACK 256 

DATASEG
prompt db 13,10,"PLEASE ENTER A CHARACTER IN THE ALPHABET.$"

CODESEG

Start:
  mov ax,@DATA
  mov dx,ax

Mainloop:
  mov ah,9
  mov dx, offset prompt
  int 21h

  mov ah,0
  int 16h

  mov ah,02h
  mov dl,"ah+32"
  int 21h
  jmp Mainloop
  
 END Start
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting lowercase character string to uppercase masm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503066/converting-lowercase-character-string-to-uppercase-masm)

Comment: NASM gives an error?  I'd expect so, that's not NASM syntax!!  Those are MASM directives.  Include the actual error messages to make this a [mcve]. `mov dl,"ah+32"` is not a syntax error, but it doesn't do what you want.  `"ah+32"` is large numeric constant, written using ASCII literals

Comment: @Peter Cordes: "Ideal" mode belongs to Turbo Assembler so I assume that is what this was meant for.

Comment: @ecm: thanks, good catch, I just saw the `end start`, and the `offset`, and didn't look more closely.  MASM and TASM are in the same family of Intel syntaxes so I could still argue that it's a MASM-family syntax :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Start:
>  mov ax,@DATA
>  mov dx,ax
> ```

The third line has an error. You want to initialize the `DS` segment register, not the general purpose register `DX`.

> im trying to take a user input, **lowercase** and convert into UPPERCASE

Your program does not make sure that the input is indeed a lowercase [a-z] but I think that's fine for now.

> `mov dl,"ah+32"`

As [Peter commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63138408/how-to-take-user-input-and-convert-to-uppercase-in-assembly#comment111652657_63138408), this instruction will not add 32 to the `AH` register!
And why would you want to?

- The (lowercase) character is in the `AL` register
- The conversion to uppercase would need you to **subtract** 32

The ASCII codes for [a-z] are [97-122]
The ASCII codes for [A-Z] are [65-90]

The real solution is to mask off the 6th bit from `AL` to get rid of that 32. In doing so, if ever the input happens to be an uppercase character already, your program will still produce the desired uppercase output. Consider that a bonus.

Next code will produce a .COM program. That's an easy program format where all the segment registers are equal to each other (`CS`==`DS`==`ES`==`SS`). The `ORG 256` directive is mandatory.

```
ORG 256

Mainloop:
  mov dx, prompt
  mov ah, 09h       ; DOS.PrintString
  int 21h

  mov ah, 00h       ; BIOS.GetKey
  int 16h           ; -> AX

  and al, 11011111b ; UCase
  mov dl, al
  mov ah, 02h       ; DOS.PrintChar
  int 21h
  jmp Mainloop

prompt db 13,10,"PLEASE ENTER A CHARACTER IN THE ALPHABET.$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add and put the result to another register in 16-bit mode (unless special cases). Try

```
mov ah, 09h ; Function: Write out string
mov dx, offset prompt
int 21h

mov ah, 00h ; Function: Read in keystroke (results in al and ah)
int 16h

mov ah, 02h ; Function: Print out character
mov dl, al  ; ASCII code of lowercase character
add dl, 32  ; To upper case
int 21h
```

There seems to be an error in the lines above too. Maybe you want to set the data segment there:

```
mov ax, seg prompt
mov ds, ax
```

Comment: That's still not NASM syntax; note the tags on the question.  Barely answerable until the OP clears up what assembler they're using.  (And then it's probably a duplicate, unless it's worth answering to explain exactly what `mov dl,"ah+32"` means in NASM syntax: a large numeric constant using an ASCII literal, which is too large to fit even in a 32-bit immediate and thus will give a warning.)